# Can the amount of salt in the recipe be right?

Tags: rice, salt, sushi

I made sushi for the first time at the weekend.  the seasoning for the rice had this recipe:

- 125 ml rice vinegar
- 30 ml mirin
- 3 tablespoons sugar
- **2 tablespoons salt**

This was for 460g rice (dry weight).

This seemed like a lot of salt to me.  Today I made some more rice, but only single quantity and I realised that last time I forgot to double the quantities of sugar and salt when making double the amount.  It was quite salty last time, but I should have put 4 tablespoons of salt in.

That can't be right can it?  What was it more likely to be?  2 Teaspoons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's been a while since I made sushi but 2 tablespoons does sound a little on the ridiculous side.

Various other recipes use similar amounts (to each other):

- [AllRecipes](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/perfect-sushi-rice/Detail.aspx): 1 tsp salt (for 1/2 cup vinegar and 4 tbsp sugar)
- [Alton Brown](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/sushi-rice-recipe/index.html): 1 tbsp kosher salt (for 2 tbsp vinegar and 2 tbsp sugar)
- [SushiRecipes](http://www.sushirecipes.org/sushi-rice.html): 1 tsp salt (for 1/2 cup vinegar and 1/2 cup sugar)
- [Epicurious](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Sushi-Rice-103278): 1/2 tsp salt (for 2 tbsp vinegar and 1 tbsp sugar)

In fact, although sushi rice recipes tend to vary significantly with respect to the proportions of rice, vinegar, and sugar, they are all remarkably consistent on the amount of salt.  The Alton Brown recipe calls for a tablespoon, but 1 tbsp of kosher salt is in fact equivalent to 1-2 tsp of table or sea salt.  Even on the Epicurious recipe, the 1/2 tsp is only for 1 cup of rice - you'd double it to the same 1 tsp for the standard 2 cups.

I assume that the recipe you're looking at must have *meant* 2 **tsp** and not **tbsp**, but I think even that is too much; I would stick to the 1 tsp used in almost every sushi rice recipe I've ever seen.